# Adapter pattern without passing class object as parameter

Tags: design-patterns, adapter

I have a really simple question. There are examples of adapter pattern on internet and in every one of them adapter class get object of class that needs to be adapted as parameter. Something like this:

```
class Adapter {
    private SomeClass someClass;

    public Adapter(SomeCLass someClass){
        this.someClass = someClass;
    }

    public adaptMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
```

If I do something like this:

```
class Adapter {
    private SomeClass someClass;

    public Adapter(){
        this.someClass = new SomeClass();
    }

    public adaptMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Would this still be an adapter pattern?

Comment: It would still be..

Comment: Is a thumbdrive a USB adapter?

Comment: If you put a real problem and solution in your code, the question would generate more light than heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is still an adapter. It matches the description and UML from the GoF, specifically the ***object adapter*** pattern.

While you might quibble over the statement that object adapters support subclasses of the adaptee...

> An object adapter lets a single Adapter work with many Adaptees -- that is, the Adaptee itself and all of its subclasses.

...I would say that's not a critical point of the pattern, and if it is, then reflection can achieve it. The pattern doesn't specify *how* the adapter must compose its adaptee. That's simply an implementation detail (the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) would have more to say about that detail).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not an adapter because it does not adapt an object of one class for use under another interface, but owns it. This violates [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

An adapter is something like a decorator. The decorator adds some functionality to the methods of the class, and the adapter changes its interface. But both need a target object.